# Unordered list button for show more/less not working on second list

Tags: jquery, html

The show less/more button (for more than 10 items) is only working for the first and third unordered list. On the second UL (also the fourth, if added) the button does nothing. I can't seem to figure out why.

HTML:

```
<ul class="tijdlijn-list">
<li class="item1"></li>
<li class="item2"></li>
<li class="item3"></li>
<li class="item4"></li>
<li class="item5"></li>
<li class="item6"></li>
<li class="item7"></li>
<li class="item8"></li>
<li class="item9"></li>
<li class="item10"></li>
<li class="item11"></li>
<li class="item12"></li>
<li class="item13"></li>
<li class="item14"></li>
<li class="item15"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="tijdlijn-list">
<li class="item1"></li>
<li class="item2"></li>
<li class="item3"></li>
<li class="item4"></li>
<li class="item5"></li>
<li class="item6"></li>
<li class="item7"></li>
<li class="item8"></li>
<li class="item9"></li>
<li class="item10"></li>
<li class="item11"></li>
<li class="item12"></li>
<li class="item13"></li>
<li class="item14"></li>
<li class="item15"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="tijdlijn-list">
<li class="item1"></li>
<li class="item2"></li>
<li class="item3"></li>
<li class="item4"></li>
<li class="item5"></li>
<li class="item6"></li>
<li class="item7"></li>
<li class="item8"></li>
<li class="item9"></li>
<li class="item10"></li>
<li class="item11"></li>
<li class="item12"></li>
<li class="item13"></li>
<li class="item14"></li>
<li class="item15"></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery script:

```
$('.tijdlijn-list').each(function(){
var max = 10;
if ($(this).find('li').length > max) {
    $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="sub_accordian"><div class="show_more">Toon alles</div></li>');
    $('.sub_accordian').click( function(){
        $(this).siblings(':gt('+max+')').toggle();
        if ( $('.show_more').length ) {
            $(this).html('<div class="show_less">Toon minder</div>');
        } else {
            $(this).html('<div class="show_more">Toon alles</div>');
        };
    });
};
});
```

Comment: Here it seems to be working fine https://jsfiddle.net/wa12rvgg/   ?

Comment: Only the second and fourth one are working for me. Have you tried all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have `$(this)` inside `onclick` event that's not triggering correctly. You can try using

```
$(this).find('.sub_accordian').click( function(){
```

So `$(this).find('.sub_accordian').click( function(){` instead of `('.sub_accordian').click(`
Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wa12rvgg/2/

Comment: As visible from example you should also use $(this).find('.show_more').length) instead of $('.show_more').length)